# I am trying to align text and image horizontally for my website

Tags: html, css

As the title suggests, I am trying to align the following image and text side by side and I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

[image]

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="projects">
                <div class="img_description">           
                <a href="https://github.com/mdanb/alexaProject"> Proj 1</a>
                <p>Answer misery adieus add wooded how nay men before though. Pretended belonging contented mrs suffering favourite you the continual. 
                    Mrs civil nay least means tried drift. Natural end law whether but and towards certain. Furnished 
                    unfeeling his sometimes see day promotion. Quitting informed concerns can men now. Projection to or up 
                    conviction uncommonly delightful continuing. In appetite ecstatic opinions hastened by handsome admitted. </p></div>
                <div class="project_image"><img src="dog.jpeg" width='250' height='250'></div>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
.projects {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: On which side do u want to have img ? on left side and on the right side u want have text?

Comment: On the left side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are using it, but maybe take a look at bootstrap.
https://getbootstrap.com/.

Bootstrap is insanely awesome when it comes to styling css.
Here is a bootstrap example of what you are trying to do:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <img src="dog.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
    <div>
    <div class="col-9">
    <a href="link"> Proj 1</a>
    <p>
        Answer misery adieus add wooded how nay men before though. Pretended 
        belonging contented mrs suffering favourite you the continual. 
        Mrs civil nay least means tried drift. Natural end law whether but and 
        towards certain. Furnished unfeeling his sometimes see day promotion. 
        Quitting informed can men now. Projection to or up conviction uncommonly 
        delightful continuing. In appetite ecstatic opinions hastened by handsome 
        admitted.
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Easily done, and bootstrap does everything for you.

That being said, maybe you do not want to use bootstrap, then you can just do the following to your current `HTML` setup.

```
<div class="projects">
    <div class="project_image">
        <img src="dog.jpeg" width='250' height='250'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="img_description">           
        <a href="link"> Proj 1</a>
    <p>
        Answer misery adieus add wooded how nay men before though. Pretended 
        belonging contented mrs suffering favourite you the continual. 
        Mrs civil nay least means tried drift. Natural end law whether but and 
        towards certain. Furnished unfeeling his sometimes see day promotion. 
        Quitting informed can men now. Projection to or up conviction uncommonly 
        delightful continuing. In appetite ecstatic opinions hastened by handsome 
        admitted.
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.projects{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.img_description,
.project_image{
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

That should also display your div's next to each other

Answer (score -1):

you can do it using flexbox, by assigning `display:flex` in your projects class. this will display the child of the `class="projects"` horizontally/row. and if you want the image to be on the left side, you should put it first followed by your image description.

```css
    .projects{
    display:flex;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="projects">
<div class="project_image"><img src="dog.jpeg" width='250' height='250'></div>
                    <div class="img_description">           
                    <a href="https://github.com/mdanb/alexaProject"> Proj 1</a>
                    <p>Answer misery adieus add wooded how nay men before though. Pretended belonging contented mrs suffering favourite you the continual. 
                        Mrs civil nay least means tried drift. Natural end law whether but and towards certain. Furnished 
                        unfeeling his sometimes see day promotion. Quitting informed concerns can men now. Projection to or up 
                        conviction uncommonly delightful continuing. In appetite ecstatic opinions hastened by handsome admitted. </p></div>
                    
            </div>
```

check out this link for more information https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ 

 hope it helps.

Comment: Although this may solve the issue, please update the answer to fit the OPs request to have the image on the left and explain a little bit how it works.

Answer (score -3):

use this css

text-align:justify;